# Drag to add power, release to throw at opposite angle (RigidBody2D), strange beahviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a total beginner and I'm making a simple 2D game, you have ball which you throw to collect pickups. I managed, following tutorials and searching on the web, to script the controls as I wanted them, when the mouse is clicked the force to apply is calculated by the movement on axis X and Y and on mouse button release the force is applied and the gravity turned on:

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        mouseDown = false;            
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0 && mouseDown)
    {            
        xForce -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 50;
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0 && mouseDown)
    {
        yForce -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 50;
    }        

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 1;

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(xForce, yForce));
        yForce = 0;
        xForce = 0;
    }
```

But while working perfectly while testing it on unity using the mouse, it behave strangely on my 2 android phones. Sometimes the ball seems to get the force only for the X axis, and even if dragging only vertically the ball has an X force applied... What could be the problem?

EDIT: I added Debug.Log(xForce) and Debug.Log(yForce) and looking at the log with adb logcat I noticed that, also when simply tapping on the screen, without dragging on neither axis, the value of those variables increase, I have really no idea on how to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would make this easier on myself by just using [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) and [Input.GetMouseButtonUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonUp.html) instead. The below method will return identical results on all platforms.

On down, set a variable like "startFirePosition = worldPosOfInput".

On up, "newForce = worldPosOfInput - startFirePosition"

You can find the world position of the input by using [Input.mousePosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) and [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Your newForce Vector2 now contains information like the drag distance ([magnitude](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-magnitude.html)), and firing direction that you can use in your firing code.

You can assign newForce directly to your rigidbody, or tweak it first to do things like increase the magnitude, clamp direction, etc.

PS, if needed you can flip the direction your newForce will take the rigidbody by flip flopping the line "worldPosOfInput - startFirePosition" to "startFirePosition - worldPosOfInput".

Comment: I get what you mean and thanks for the suggestion, but trying to implement this, I don't get what "worldPosOfInput" and "currentWorldPosOfInput" are or how to get them... I apologize for my noobness, but can find any reference to them anywhere :)

Comment: I like to leave my answers in pseudo-code to make sure I'm not just doing the work for the person (instead of helping them learn), but I am more than happy to give more help where needed!

Those are variables that you will need to find yourself using [Input.mousePosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) and [Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Comment: @RingK I updated the answer to be a little more informative :)